# Is there any way to query double nested in Firebase Realtime?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

[image: Data structure of database]

I want to query by **userId** from the parent that is **comments** in the Firebase Cloud Functions. But I don't get anyway how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already tried something yet?

Comment: are you wanna this in javascript